# How can I add conditional logic to fill certain rows of a dataframe with certain strings when certain conditions are met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write some Python logic to fill a **csv file/pandas dataframe table** called (`table`) with certain conditions, but I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

I have two **columns** in `table`: 1. `trade_type` and 2. `execution_venue`.

**Conditional statement I want to write in Python**:

The `execution_venue` entry will only be filled with either `AQXE` or `AQEU`, depending on the `trade_type`.

When the `trade_type` is filled with the string `DARK`, I want the the `execution_venue` to be filled with `XUBS` (if it was filled with `AQXE` before), and `AQED` (if it was filled with `AQEU` before).

Here is my code to do this:

```
security_mic = ('AQXE', 'AQEU')
table.loc[table['trade_type'] == 'DARK', 'execution_venue'] = {'AQXE': 'XUBS',
                                                                               'AQEU': 'AQED'}.get(security_mic)
```

When I replace the right hand side of the equality with a string `test`, I am getting the same error, so I suspect the error is to do with the left hand side, in that it is not accessing the correct place in the dataframe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets use `replace` for substitution of old values where `trade_type` os `DARK`

```
d = {'AQXE': 'XUBS', 'AQEU': 'AQED'}
table.loc[table['trade_type'] == 'DARK', 'execution_venue'] = table['execution_venue'].replace(d)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it- the code flow is quite long so it will take a bit of time to test. But on first glace it looks like it will work.